# Using .sh file to compile commands in source code

Tags: linux, fortran

I am using FORTRAN to solve partial differentiate equations. Main program and subroutines have been put in .f file. And I got a .sh file to compile the commands in source code in linux operating system. This file has been attached. But I failed to run this. After struggling for a week, I really need some help on this. Please any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

```
#!/bin/bash
#
mkdir temp
cd temp
rm *
~/binc/$ARCH/f77split ../fishpack.f
#
for FILE in `ls -1 *.f`;
do
  gfortran -c -g $FILE >& compiler.txt
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Errors compiling " $FILE
    exit
  fi
  rm compiler.txt
done
rm *.f
#
ar qc libfishpack.a *.o
rm *.o
#
mv libfishpack.a ~/libf77/$ARCH
cd ..
rmdir temp
#
echo "Library installed as ~/libf77/$ARCH/libfishpack.a."
```

Comment: How did you run it? What was the error?

Comment: What response to you get when you execute `echo $ARCH` at the command line ?

Comment: Trying running the script with the `-x` option for verbose ouput `bash -x compile.sh` might make the problem clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @choroba. I run this .sh file in the terminal by chmod +x filename.sh

Comment: `chmod` changes permissions. It does not run the script. Type `./filename.sh` afterwards to actually run it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @choroba. I run this .sh file in the terminal by chmod +x filename.sh and then filename.sh. The fishpack.f is the source file. One of the warnings goes: c:command not found. I programmed in FORTRAN77 and run it in Linux in VMware.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @HighPerformanceMark. I get a blank line after execute echo $ARCH

Comment: Thanks for the help, @sudo_O! It remains the same. Any other advice?

Comment: Have you looked into using a Makefile?

Comment: What does ~/binc/$ARCH/f77split ../fishpack.f do?  Does it split the files into the current directory?  If you get a blank line when you echo $ARCH it means that ARCH isn't set.  Use env to check your environment variables before you run filename.sh

Comment: Thanks for your advice, @cup!! I have changed the path to "/home/tux/fishpack.f"to avoid this problem. One of the warnings goes: c:command not found. I programmed in FORTRAN77 and run it in Linux in VMware. Why can't it know "c"??

Comment: I am sorry... what's a Makefile? @SuperCow

Comment: Can you tell me what "`ls -1 *.f`" mean?? Please~~~ @choroba

Comment: to find a .f file, right? @choroba

Comment: @user2642499: Type `man ls` to find out more about `ls`.

Comment: @user2642499: A Makefile is sort of like a shell script, except it is specifically designed to help with building programs. If you're going to be working in Linux with large programs for any length of time I would suggest looking into them. [Wikipedia Entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the shell script is simply trying to compile a fortran file, but instead of using gfortran's internal toolchain, it is compiling parts manually then linking them together.  I have a feeling (though I haven't confirmed) that the call to the program `ar` is bad, even if it got that far (I'm guessing it should be `ar -qc instead of ar qc`.).

Anyway, if all the source is in a single fortran file that someone else gave you (fishpack.f), you might be able to compile the whole thing with a single call to gfortran:

```
gfortran fishpack.f
```

It should create (by default) an output executable with a filename `a.out`.  If the fortran code is not structured such that it can be lumped into a single file, you may need to work on separating some things out (--as well as updating to at least f90, though that's an aside--).

Good luck.